# Input pyhon, but auto type return

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, input, types

guys, is any decision to get auto type return from input in pyhon? I mean, if I need to get argument from input for if construction that makes choice by type of this argument.

Tried to search decision, no result.

Comment: In 3.x. `input` always returns a string. You need to try to convert to your expected type. Ex: `my_integer_value = int(input("Enter a number: ")`

Answer (score 0):

```
def userGrade():
    userInput = int(input("Type a number that is greater than five: "))

    if userInput > 5:
        print(f"{userInput} is greater than five. You passed first grade!")
        return None
    else:
        print(f"{userInput} is less than six, not greater than five! You failed first grade math!!!")
        return 1

if userGrade() == 1:
     print("Time for first grade!")
     likeFirstGrade = input("Do you like first grade? (Yes, or no): ")[0].lower()
     if likeFirstGrade == "y":
         print("ZGood for you!")
     else:
         print("You still must take it!")
```

For this small amount of code user input influences the program.